# Selenium upload file - element not interactable

Tags: python, html, .net, selenium

I need to pass "C:\temp\register.xlsx" to the upload window when it opens, using the selenium webdriver using python, however since I'm new to selenium and html, I'm unable to properly understand what items from the html I need to grab and how to correctly format it.
I'm on windows 10 using chrome and python 3.

I investigated and found some clues around html hidden objects, however I've tried alternatives without much criterion.

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:\\Drivers\\chromedriver.exe')
browser.get('https://someinternalsite.int/')

browser.find_element_by_name('txtUsername').send_keys('user')
browser.find_element_by_name('txtPassword').send_keys('pass')
browser.find_element_by_name('cmdLogin').click()
browser.get('https://user@someinternalsite.int/next/adm/exportacion/exportboletines/')
browser.find_element_by_name('TxtFechaDesde.Text')
browser.find_element_by_name('TxtFechaHasta.Text')

file_input = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="FileAdjunto_lisearch"]')
browser.execute_script('arguments[0].style = ""; arguments[0].style.display = "block"; arguments[0].style.visibility = "visible";', file_input)
file_input.send_keys("C:\temp\register.xlsx")
```

Here's the html element copied:

```
<li id="FileAdjunto_lisearch"><button class="mv-btn-xs mv-btn--rounded mv-btn--outline mv-btn--primary mv-control--file__search mv-media__btn mv-btn" data-action="" id="FileAdjunto_Search_Id_Main_Container" tabindex="-1" title="Cargar" type="button"><i aria-hidden="true" class="mv-icon--search mv-icon "></i></button></li>
```

but I don't even know if this portion of html code is the correct from where I have to get the elements.

When time comes the time to open the upload window, I get this:
"selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable"

Any assistance would be much appreciated.

thank you

Comment: Consider using `AutoIt` as you don't have `<input type='file'>`.

Comment: Quick question, do you have the `li` element in a form?

Comment: It's a form build by third party. Is it a bad practice or has it any relation with the issue?

Comment: Hello there, so is AutoIt the only way to go? Thank you!